# When reviewing suggested edit, an overlay covers over the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editing

For this question: [Does your heart skip a beat when you sneeze?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8633/651)
I see there is a suggested edit:

[image: sugg]

But then The page has an overlay which I cannot get through and I have no choice but to refresh the page! (or pressing escape which both removes the overlay and the dialog)

[image: sugg overlay]

Comment: I've reproduced that, it looks the same to me. I did remove the div that was blocking the page by hand and approved the edit.

Comment: arrrg @Fabian... now it will be [meta-tag:status-norepro]..... That was silly :-P

Comment: is this still happening?

Comment: @SeanGallagher I am not sure. do you have a suggested edit I can test it on?

Comment: no :/ I think we've got it fixed between a few of us. We will push this out to dev servers and test.

Comment: @SeanGallagher can you suggest an edit on that question. ill test again.

Comment: this has been fixed on dev. It will push with the next build.

Comment: @SeanGallagher K thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. 
the Div ID answers had a position:realtive and it is now removed.

Sorry about the bold

Comment: **WHOA** THAT IS BOLD :-P

Comment: haha. sorry. Not sure how that happened. LIVE BOLDLY!